# Perl Text Extraction

Tags: regex, perl

I just need to extract the numbers in each of these items and store them separately, whats the best way to do this ?
 IF the data is something like
 
p °c 4'i
App data usage stats
E
iii
! 12:12PM
Received data
Sent data
Current usage
598KB
28KB
626KB :18%
Get Current Stat Browser App
J
Battery Level

I tried this, but I get only 18 as an output in this case.

```
foreach my $line (@lines) {
if ($line =~/ :[ ]*(\d+)[ ]*(KB|%)/) {

$value = $1;
print "the value is $value\n";
    push (@array, $1);
}
```

}

Thanks,

Comment: It would be nice if you show your code, what have you done so far?

Comment: Though Reza has answered the query I feel I should point you in the direction of perl's excellent regex documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Comment: Please refer to the edit in the post.

Answer (score 4):

Loop over every line, and using a regular expression

```
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ /(\d+)/) {
        push (@array, $1);
    }
}
```

And you'll have all the numbers in your `@array` array

Comment: thank you, while this works only if there are these three lines for extraction...if there are many more lines with other numerical information.. the unique way to do this would be to extract the number between : and KB or : and %  in each line... am i correct ? if thats right..how to do it..

Comment: Look at nickisfat's comment on the question. The docs are great. If you want the descriptions as well as the numbers, have a look at [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). You might want to put that into a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Note that it does not care about which kind of numbers it extracts, as per your request.

It splits the line on colons in max two fields, key and value. Then we extract numbers from the values and insert into the hash. This part will effectively skip all lines where values do not contain numbers. This is also where you would insert stricter checks, e.g. `if ($value =~ /(\d+)\s*KB/i)` would only capture numbers followed by `KB` (I opted to add case insensitivity).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($key, $value) = split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2;
    if ($value =~ /(\d+)/) {
        $hash{$key} = $1;
    }
}
print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
Received data : 598 KB
Sent data : 28 KB
Current usage : 626 KB
Battery Level : 35 %
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Sent data' => '28',
          'Current usage' => '626',
          'Battery Level' => '35',
          'Received data' => '598'
        };
```